# How to keep track of a variable with Clang's static analyzer?

Tags: clang, static-analysis, clang-static-analyzer

Suppose I'm working with the following C snippet:

```
void inc(int *num) {*num++;}
void dec(int *num) {*num--;}

void f(int var) {
    inc(&var);
    dec(&var);
}
```

By using a static analyzer, I want to be able to tell if the value of *var* didn't change during the function's execution. I know I have to keep its state on my own (that's the point of writing a Clang checker), but I'm having troubles getting a unique reference of this variable.

For example: if I use the following API

```
void MySimpleChecker::checkPostCall(const CallEvent &Call,
                                    CheckerContext &C) const {
    SymbolRef MyArg = Call.getArgSVal(0).getAsSymbol();
}
```

I'd expect it to return a pointer to this symbol's representation in my checker's context. However, I always get **0** into *MyArg* by using it this way. This happens for both *inc* and *dec* functions in the *pre* and *post* callbacks.

What am I missing here? What concepts did I get wrong?

Note: I'm currently reading the [Clang CFE Internals Manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html) and I've read the excellent [How to Write a Checker in 24 Hours](http://llvm.org/devmtg/2012-11/Zaks-Rose-Checker24Hours.pdf) material. I still couldn't find my answer so far.

Comment: Can you provide more details of your implementation? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your approach. Maybe your implementation has some issues.

Comment: I've used SimpleStreamChecker as a reference. In the checkPostCall method, I've commented out the two "if" checks and them used the statement provided above. You can check it by modifying your build of clang and running this checker in the code provided in the question. I'm using revision 208276.

Comment: Probably slightly unrelated, but your code example should compile to nothing because f() doesn't store int var anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Interpretation of question

Specifically, you want to count the calls to `inc` and `dec` applied to each variable and report when they do not balance for some path in a function.

Generally, you want to know how to associate an abstract value, here a number, with a program variable, and be able to update and query that value along each execution path.

### High-level answer

Whereas the tutorial checker [`SimpleStreamChecker.cpp`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/clang/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/SimpleStreamChecker.cpp) associates an abstract value with the value stored *in* a variable, here we want associate an abstract value with the variable itself.  That is what [`IteratorChecker.cpp`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/clang/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/IteratorChecker.cpp) does when tracking containers, so I based my solution on it.

Within the static analyzer's abstract state, each variable is represented by a [`MemRegion`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ento_1_1MemRegion.html) object.  So the first step is to make a map where `MemRegion` is the key:

```cc
REGISTER_MAP_WITH_PROGRAMSTATE(TrackVarMap, MemRegion const *, int)
```

Next, when we have an [`SVal`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ento_1_1SVal.html) that corresponds to a pointer to a variable, we can use [`SVal::getAsRegion`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ento_1_1SVal.html#ad672f790d7d4e0b4c63428f963caaa36) to get the corresponding `MemRegion`.  For instance, given a [`CallEvent`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ento_1_1CallEvent.html), `call`, with a first argument that is a pointer, we can do:

```cc
    if (MemRegion const *region = call.getArgSVal(0).getAsRegion()) {
```

to get the `region` that the pointer points at.

Then, we can access our map using that `region` as its key:

```cc
      state = state->set<TrackVarMap>(region, newValue);
```

Finally, in [`checkDeadSymbols`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ento_1_1CheckerDocumentation.html#a9aa73365ae3aa929641d6bdb989ac79e), we use [`SymbolReaper::isLiveRegion`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ento_1_1SymbolReaper.html#a78fba4ee410f8e29b0ca43d07a83fd6b) to detect when a region (variable) is going out of scope:

```cc
  const TrackVarMapTy &Map = state->get<TrackVarMap>();
  for (auto const &I : Map) {
    MemRegion const *region = I.first;
    int delta = I.second;
    if (SymReaper.isLiveRegion(region) || (delta==0))
      continue;              // Not dead, or unchanged; skip.
```

### Complete example

To demonstrate, here is a complete checker that reports unbalanced use of `inc` and `dec`:

```cc
// TrackVarChecker.cpp
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448540/how-to-keep-track-of-a-variable-with-clangs-static-analyzer

#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/BuiltinCheckerRegistration.h"
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/BugReporter/BugType.h"
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/Checker.h"
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/CheckerManager.h"
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/PathSensitive/CallEvent.h"
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/PathSensitive/CheckerContext.h"
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/PathSensitive/ProgramState.h"
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/PathSensitive/ProgramStateTrait.h"

using namespace clang;
using namespace ento;

namespace {
class TrackVarChecker
  : public Checker< check::PostCall,
                    check::DeadSymbols >
{
  mutable IdentifierInfo *II_inc, *II_dec;
  mutable std::unique_ptr<BuiltinBug> BT_modified;

public:
  TrackVarChecker() : II_inc(nullptr), II_dec(nullptr) {}

  void checkPostCall(CallEvent const &Call, CheckerContext &C) const;
  void checkDeadSymbols(SymbolReaper &SymReaper, CheckerContext &C) const;
};
} // end anonymous namespace

// Map from memory region corresponding to a variable (that is, the
// variable itself, not its current value) to the difference between its
// current and original value.
REGISTER_MAP_WITH_PROGRAMSTATE(TrackVarMap, MemRegion const *, int)

void TrackVarChecker::checkPostCall(CallEvent const &call, CheckerContext &C) const
{
  const FunctionDecl *FD = dyn_cast<FunctionDecl>(call.getDecl());
  if (!FD || FD->getKind() != Decl::Function) {
    return;
  }

  ASTContext &Ctx = C.getASTContext();
  if (!II_inc) {
    II_inc = &Ctx.Idents.get("inc");
  }
  if (!II_dec) {
    II_dec = &Ctx.Idents.get("dec");
  }

  if (FD->getIdentifier() == II_inc || FD->getIdentifier() == II_dec) {
    // We expect the argument to be a pointer.  Get the memory region
    // that the pointer points at.
    if (MemRegion const *region = call.getArgSVal(0).getAsRegion()) {
      // Increment the associated value, creating it first if needed.
      ProgramStateRef state = C.getState();
      int delta = (FD->getIdentifier() == II_inc)? +1 : -1;
      int const *curp = state->get<TrackVarMap>(region);
      int newValue = (curp? *curp : 0) + delta;
      state = state->set<TrackVarMap>(region, newValue);
      C.addTransition(state);
    }
  }
}

void TrackVarChecker::checkDeadSymbols(
  SymbolReaper &SymReaper, CheckerContext &C) const
{
  ProgramStateRef state = C.getState();
  const TrackVarMapTy &Map = state->get<TrackVarMap>();
  for (auto const &I : Map) {
    // Check for a memory region (variable) going out of scope that has
    // a non-zero delta.
    MemRegion const *region = I.first;
    int delta = I.second;
    if (SymReaper.isLiveRegion(region) || (delta==0)) {
      continue;              // Not dead, or unchanged; skip.
    }

    //llvm::errs() << region << " dead with delta " << delta << "\n";
    if (ExplodedNode *N = C.generateNonFatalErrorNode()) {
      if (!BT_modified) {
        BT_modified.reset(
          new BuiltinBug(this, "Delta not zero",
                         "Variable changed from its original value."));
      }
      C.emitReport(llvm::make_unique<BugReport>(
        *BT_modified, BT_modified->getDescription(), N));
    }
  }
}

void ento::registerTrackVarChecker(CheckerManager &mgr) {
  mgr.registerChecker<TrackVarChecker>();
}

bool ento::shouldRegisterTrackVarChecker(const LangOptions &LO) {
  return true;
}
```

To hook this in to the rest of Clang, add entries to:

- `clang/include/clang/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/Checkers.td` and
- `clang/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/CMakeLists.txt`

Example input to test it:

```c
// trackvar.c
// Test for TrackVarChecker.

// The behavior of these functions is hardcoded in the checker.
void inc(int *num);
void dec(int *num);

void call_inc(int var) {
  inc(&var);
} // reported

void call_inc_dec(int var) {
  inc(&var);
  dec(&var);
} // NOT reported

void if_inc(int var) {
  if (var > 2) {
    inc(&var);
  }
} // reported

void indirect_inc(int val) {
  int *p = &val;
  inc(p);
} // reported
```

Sample run:

```
$ gcc -E -o trackvar.i trackvar.c
$ ~/bld/llvm-project/build/bin/clang -cc1 -analyze -analyzer-checker=alpha.core.TrackVar trackvar.i
trackvar.c:10:1: warning: Variable changed from its original value
}
^
trackvar.c:21:1: warning: Variable changed from its original value
}
^
trackvar.c:26:1: warning: Variable changed from its original value
}
^
3 warnings generated.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the check that this call event is a call to your function inc/dec. You should have something like

```
void MySimpleChecker::checkPostCall(const CallEvent &Call,
                                CheckerContext &C) const {
    const IdentifierInfo* callee = Call.getCalleeIdentifier();
    if (callee->getName().str() == "inc" || callee->getName().str() == "dec")
        SymbolRef MyArg = Call.getArgSVal(0).getAsSymbol();
}
```

Comment: This is not helpful. Just checking the function name of the callee doesn't change anything.